# What is the best way to add a parent group to user groups in userfrosting?

Tags: php, mysql, authorization, access-control, userfrosting

I'm new here and this is my first question.
First of all I apologize for my poor English.
I would like to create an application using userfrosting 0.3.0 where:

- Anyone not registered can create a super group (eg a company)
- At that time an administrator user is created, other than root, but can only read information from the supergroup (administrators can not see other companies)
- Administrators can organize your users inside user-groups, but only root can create groups and modify permissions

I thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Should be doable.  Who gets to create new users in a company?  The administrator of the company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserFrosting, as of version 0.3.1, does not have built-in support for group hierarchies.  However, it should be pretty easy to implement.  Here is how I would do it:

1. Create two groups, "Administrators" and "Members".  Set it up so that "Administrator" is the [default primary group](http://www.userfrosting.com/components/#groups) for new users.
2. Create two tables, `company` and `company_user`.  The `company` table will store information about the companies, with a primary key `id`.  The `company_user` table will associate companies with users, and have four columns:

   - `id` (int)
   - `company_id` (int)
   - `user_id` (int)
   - `flag_admin` (bool)

Change the `register()` method in `AccountController.php` so that when someone registers, it creates a new company and then associates them with this company, marking them as the Administrator of this company by setting `flag_admin` to '1'.

Any members that get added to a specific company should also be added to this table, but with `flag_admin` set to '0'.

3. Create a new [`AccessCondition`](https://github.com/alexweissman/UserFrosting/blob/master/userfrosting/models/auth/AccessCondition.php) called `manages(user_id_1, user_id_2)` which returns `true` if `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` belong to the same company **and** `user_id_1` has `flag_admin` set to '1', `false` otherwise.
4. Grant appropriate permissions to users in group "Administrators" so that they can create/update/delete/view users, but only users in group "Members" and only if the Administrator `manage`s them (so if "Members" has a group_id of "4", condition=`in_group(user.id,4)&&manages(self.id,user.id)`.
5. You will also want to modify the various user create/update/delete methods so that when an Administrator creates a user, it adds them to group "Member" and associates them with the appropriate company.

That should get you started, let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do it. However I find it interesting the group hierarchies. It will be implemented in the future?

Comment: It is "under consideration".  We'll have to decide if the added complexity is worth making it a core feature.